# Browser is blocking Oauth2.0 login check on deployed version of MERN app (CORS)

Tags: javascript, express, oauth-2.0, cors, mern

I have created a MERN web app (React front end, node backend), and wish to deploy it. For login, I am using Passport/OAuth2.0. The flow is: user clicks 'sign in with google/github/etc.', user signs in, user gets let into rest of app.

Everything works on localhost. However, when I deploy it, certain browsers seem to block not the actual login, but the check that the app makes after the user has been redirected to the login screen. For example, chrome does not work but safari does. My friend who has different preferences couldn't even get it to work in safari.

The `useEffect` in `app.js` makes a call to `/auth/login/success` in `auth.js`. If the user has logged in, it returns a 200. If not, it returns a 400. This works on localhost. However, on the deployed version, even if the user has logged in (i.e. login with google, redirect back to homepage), it returns a 400 with the following error in the console when I console.log the response.

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcSGh.png)

It says the type of error is 'cors', but it this isn't the usual 'CORS has blocked the following policy' error that we usually see (and my server.js it configured right for that). This seems to be a browser specific problem that only happens on the deployed version.

I've attached my server.js, auth.js, passport.js, and app.js

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const users = require('./routes/api/users');
const python = require('./routes/api/python');
const newjobs = require('./routes/api/newjobs');
const userjobs = require('./routes/api/userjobs');
const events = require('./routes/api/events');
const startup = require('./routes/api/startup');
const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
const cors = require("cors");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportSetup = require("./auth/passport")
const authRoute = require("./routes/api/auth")


const app = express();

app.use(cookieSession(
    {name: "session",
    keys: ["blah"],
    maxAge: 2*24*60*60*100}
));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(cors({
    origin: "https://deployed-client.com",
    methods: "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE",
    credentials: true
}))

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://deployed-client.com);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    next();
});

app.use(express.json());

const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() =>
        console.log('MongoDB successfully connected.')
    ).catch(err => console.log(err));


app.use("/auth", authRoute);
app.use('/', users);
app.use('/', python)
app.use('/', newjobs);
app.use('/', userjobs);
app.use('/', events);
app.use('/', startup);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server up and running on port ${port} !`));
```

**auth.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require("passport");

const CLIENT_URL = "https://deployed-client.com/"

router.get("/login/failed", (req,res) => {
    res.status(401).json({
        success: false,
        message: "failure",
        req: req
    })
})

router.get("/login/success", (req,res) => {
    if (req.user) {
        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: "successful",
            user: req.user,
        })
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            message: "failed",
        })
    }
})

router.get("/logout", (req,res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect(CLIENT_URL);
})

router.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google", {scope: ["profile", "email"]}));

router.get("/google/callback", passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: CLIENT_URL,
    failureRedirect: "/login/failed"
}));

router.get("/github", passport.authenticate("github", {scope: ["profile", "email"]}));

router.get("/github/callback", passport.authenticate("github", {
    successRedirect: CLIENT_URL,
    failureRedirect: "/login/failed"
}));

module.exports = router;
```

**passport.js**

```
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const GithubStrategy = require("passport-github2").Strategy;
const passport = require("passport");

const GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = ;
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = ;

const GITHUB_CLIENT_ID = ;
const GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET = ;

passport.use(new GithubStrategy({
    clientID: GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "/auth/github/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    done(null,profile)
  }
));

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
    scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'],
    userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo",

  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    done(null,profile);
  }
));

passport.serializeUser((user,done)=> {
    done(null,user)
});

passport.deserializeUser((user,done)=> {
    done(null,user)
});
```

**app.js**

```
const App = () => {

  const [user, editUser] = useState(null);
  const [selected, editSelected] = useState("dashboard");
  const [signedInWithPassport, editSignedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = () => {
      fetch(`${API_URL}/auth/login/success`, {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
        },
      })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          if (response.status === 200) return response.json();
          throw new Error("authentication has been failed!");
        })
        .then((resObject) => {
          editSignedIn(true);
          editUser(resObject.user);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          editSignedIn(false);
        });
    };
    getUser();
  }, []);

  const logout = () => {
    if (signedInWithPassport) {
      window.open(`${API_URL}/auth/logout`,"_self");
    } else {
      editUser(null);
    }
  }
return (...);
```